# EF Code First Duplicate Foreign Key for same table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have been reading SO posts about EF Code First generating duplicate foreign keys and tried to apply the solution to my code but unable to fix my code.

Here are my classes

```
 public class Schedule
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }
}

public class Appointment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Schedule Schedule { get; set; }
}

public class ScheduleConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Schedule>
{
    public ScheduleConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(s => s.Id);
        Property(s => s.Id).HasColumnName("SCHEDULEID");            
        ToTable("SCHEDULES");
    }        
}

public class AppointmentConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Appointment>
{
    public AppointmentConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(a => a.Id);
        Property(a => a.Id).HasColumnName("APPOINTMENTID");            
        HasRequired(a => a.Schedule).WithMany().Map(x => x.MapKey("SCHEDULEID"));
        ToTable("APPOINTMENTS");
    }
}
```

This is generating two foreign keys in `appointments` table namely `SCHEDULEID` and `Schedule_Id1`.

How can I tell EF not to create `Schedule_Id1`

Comment: now fk is Schedule_Id which I wanted to be SCHEDULEID

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just try this :

```
HasRequired(a => a.Schedule).WithMany(x=> x.Appointment).Map(x => x.MapKey("SCHEDULEID"));
```

Hope this help.

Comment: I added this just to name the foreign key as SCHEDULEID instead of Schedule_Id which is created by convention

Comment: tnx:) that fixed the issue.. Don't know I thought WithMany() should be empty if used in configuration class. We should better try things rather than assuming..

Answer (score 1):

You can use InverseProperty data annotation in property Appointments

```
public class Schedule
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Schedule")]
    public virtual ICollection<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }
}

public class Appointment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Schedule Schedule { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: same issue. Schedule_Id is created instead of SCHEDULEID